# File Upload Handling: Inconsistent HTTP Response Codes for Different File Sizes with Exception in Tomcat

Tags: javascript, tomcat, file-upload

When uploading files smaller than 5MB that trigger a server-side exception, the server correctly responds with a 500 Internal Server Error, as expected.
However, for files larger than 5MB that also trigger an exception, instead of a 500 error, the client receives a net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error.
This inconsistency in behavior for different file sizes is puzzling, especially since the maxPostSize setting should theoretically allow for files of any size, and I would expect the server to consistently return a 500 error for all exceptions.
This phenomenon does not occur in **HTTPS** environments. only **HTTP**

**upload.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>File Upload Example</title>
</head>

<body>

  <h2>File Upload to JSP</h2>

  <input type="file" id="fileInput" name="file">
  <button onclick="uploadFile()">Upload File</button>

  <script>
    function uploadFile() {
      var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
      var file = fileInput.files[0];
      var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', file);

      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('POST', './upload1.jsp', true);
      xhr.addEventListener('load', function () {
        console.log('done', xhr.responseText);
      });
      xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (e) {
        console.log('progress', e.loaded, e.total);
      });
      xhr.addEventListener('error', function (e) {
        console.log('error', e);
      });
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        console.log(xhr.readyState, xhr.status)
      }
      xhr.send(formData);
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

**upload1.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html;charset=utf-8" %>
<%
try{
    int a = 10/0; // 서버 측 예외 상황 시뮬레이션
}catch(Exception e){
    response.setStatus(response.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}
%>
```

Using tomcat 8.5, and configuring maxPostSize to -1 in Tomcat to allow unlimited file sizes